# Example that isometry doesn't preserve extrinsic distance

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there any example that an isometry doesn't preserve the extrinsic distance? That is, I want some example that for some isometry $f:S\to\tilde{S}$ between connected regular surfaces such that it doesn't satisfy this property: $|f(p)-f(q)| = |p-q|$ for all $p,q\in S$.

Comment: Here is a complicated answer: by the Nash-Kuiper theorem, you can isometrically embed the unit sphere into a ball of radius 1/2. Thus, this embedding provides an isometry between the unit sphere and a surface lying inside the ball of radius 1/2, and it clearly does not respect extrinsic distance.

Comment: @DIdier_ Oh, that's interesting. But I've never heard about the Nash-Kuiper theorem (I'm taking introductory level differential geometry course). There must be less complicated example. But anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a rectangle in a plane and the corresponding portion of a (right circular) cylinder.

Comment: Oh, that's the easiest example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest and most obvious example. When you're satisfied with one of our answers, you should accept it so that the question no longer remains unanswered.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I gave a complicated answer (using Nash-Kuiper theorem). But here is a much more simple example. Let $\mathbb{S}^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit circle, and let $\mathcal{E}_{a,b} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \}$ be an ellipse. Chose $a<b$ such that this ellipse has length $2\pi$, and then is isometric to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

The arc-length parametrization of the ellipse gives an isometry between the circle and the ellipse that does not preserve the extrinsic distance in the plane. One can see this because antipodal points in the circle has constant distance $2$, while in the ellipse, it varies between $2a$ and $2b$.

Comment: Thanks. You helped a lot